# Integrating over a piecewise function with a condition

Tags: integration

Define

$$g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
h(x)/x & \text{if}  \text{ } 0 < y < x \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise.} \\
\end{cases} $$

where $\int_{0}^{\infty} h(x) \mathop{dx} = 1$ and $h$ is not negative. $g$ is defined on $(0, \infty)$.

Find

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x, y) \mathop{dx} \mathop{ dy}.$$

---

I am pretty sure that the change of bounds will force both of the lower bounds to be $0$, but I need a good explanation for the upper bound.

I guess that it is

$$\int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x, y) \mathop{dx dy} $$

Comment: Pedantic Comment: you are integrating the piecewise-defined function... OVER the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a small comment: in your last equation you have $\int_0^x \mathrm{d}y$ outside the $x$ integral, which doesn't make sense since $x$ is a dummy variable being integrated over. But you're on the right track.

The integral only receives contributions when $g \neq 0$ which is for $0<y<x$. Hence (for each $x\ge 0$) you might as well only integrate over $y \in (0,x)$. $x<0$ doesn't do anything. Thus we get to $\int_0^\infty  \left[ \int_0^x \mathrm{d}y \cdots \right] \mathrm{d}x$.

To help you understand problems like this more generally, by far the clearest explanation is to draw a picture of the $(x,y)$ plane and shade in the region where $g \neq 0$ (i.e. $0<y<x$). Now you want to find a nice parametrization of the shaded area and integrate over the parameters.